# Xamarin - Is there a Load Function

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a question about Xamarin Studio. I am building a application that connects with a server to get data from the server. I've made a function for the connection.

Also i've made a second view that opens when the user presses a button. When the view loads i would like to call my connect function to get all the data.

So i would like to know if there is a Load event in Xamarin studio. 
This is the function i am looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several. One of them is `ViewDidLoad`, which runs after a View has loaded. Xamarin is not a direct port of Windows Forms, which means MSDN will be of little help - you need to learn how iOS works.

**However, there is [Xamarin Forms](http://xamarin.com/forms), which is a cross-platform UI toolkit that may be the right choice for you. It abstracts away the need for knowing iOS or Android UI details.** You may think of it as "Windows Forms for iOS/Android/Phone". Even if you're only ever targetting iOS, Xamarin Forms can help you build an UI.

In this specific case, the ["Hello, iOS" Xamarin quickstart tutorial](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS/hello,iOS_quickstart/) has a good example of responding to events such as a view loading.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, is there something like an onload function

Comment: Yes there is. It's covered in the quickstart tutorial. Go play with it! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I will mark this as awnser as soon as possible